# Event Loop async.waterfall node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js

I need to read the first and second files and write to the third file with async.waterfall. When I write to the third file, I can’t get the data of 1, 2 files. How can this be implemented?

```
const unionFiles = (file1, file2, file3, cb) => {
  waterfall([
      fs.readFile(file1, 'utf-8', (err1, data1) => {
      callback(err1, data1);
    }),
    fs.readFile(file2, 'utf-8', (err2, data1, data2) => {
      cb(err2, data1, data2);
    }),
    fs.writeFile(file3, `${data1}${data2}`, (err3, data1, data2) => {
      cb(err3, data1, data2);
    })
  ]),
  cb(null);
}
```

Comment: what is ```data2``` in second readFile

Comment: Its better to understand async process and respective async functions from base to avoid errors in your projects as node.js is all of that.

Comment: @MayankGupta this is the data of the second file

Answer (score 0):

As I can see in the documentation.

```
async.waterfall([
  function(callback) {
    callback(null, 'Task 1', 'Task 2');
  },
  function(arg1, arg2, callback) {
    // arg1 now equals 'Task 1' and arg2 now equals 'Task 2'
    let arg3 = arg1 + ' and ' + arg2;
    callback(null, arg3);
  },
  function(arg1, callback) {
    // arg1 now equals 'Task1 and Task2'
    arg1 += ' completed';
    callback(null, arg1);
  }
], function(err, result) {
  // result now equals to 'Task1 and Task2 completed'
  console.log(result);
});
```

Alternatively

It will run one function at a time and pass the result of the previous function to the next one.

```
async.waterfall([
  myFirstFunction,
  mySecondFunction,
  myLastFunction,
], function(err, result) {
  // result now equals 'Task1 and Task2 completed'
  console.log(result);
});

function myFirstFunction(callback) {
  callback(null, 'Task 1', 'Task 2');
}
function mySecondFunction(arg1, arg2, callback) {
  // arg1 now equals 'Task 1' and arg2 now equals 'Task 2'
  let arg3 = arg1 + ' and ' + arg2;
  callback(null, arg3);
}
function myLastFunction(arg1, callback) {
  // arg1 now equals 'Task1 and Task2'
  arg1 += ' completed';
  callback(null, arg1);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In Waterfall function, the result values are passed as arguments, in order, to the next task.

Also first arguments in callback is reserved for Error. So when this line is executed

```
callback(err1, data1);
```

That means an error is thrown. So next function will not be called.

Have updated your code. Final code could something like this:

```
const unionFiles = (file1, file2, file3, cb) => {
const params:any = {};
        params.file1 = file1;
        params.file2 = file2;
        params.file3= file3;


let tasks:Function[]= [];
  tasks.push(async.constant(params))  
  //Tasks will be executed in order
  tasks.push(readFile1, readFile2,writeFile);
  async.waterfall(
  tasks,
  function(err, result){
      // Handle Error here
  }),cb(null);
}

    function readFileF1(params,callback){
      fs.readFile(params.file1, 'utf-8', (err1, data1) => {
      if(err1)
       callback(err1);
      callback(null, params,data1);
    });
    
    }
    
    function readFileF2(params,data1,callback){
      fs.readFile(params.file2, 'utf-8', (err2, data2) => {
      if(err1)
       callback(err2);
      callback(null, params,data1+data2);
    });
    
    }
    
    function writeFile(params,combinedData,callback){
      fs.writeFile(prams.file3, 'utf-8', (err2, data1) => {
      if(err1)
       callback(err2);
      callback(null);
    });
    
    }
```

The other method of achieving the same result is to use a promise library like BlueBird:

```
var fs = require('fs');
var readFile = Promise.promisify(fs.readFile);
var writeFile = Promise.promisify(fs.writeFile);
var Promise = require('bluebird');

var promiseArray = [readFile('file1.txt'), readFile('file2.txt')];

Promise.all(promiseArray).then((dataArray)=>{
     var data = '';
     for(var i=0;i<dataArray.length;i++){
          data += dataArray[i];
     }
     return writeFile('file3.txt', data);
});
```